# How to use extends for this angulr2 scenario?

Tags: oop, angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-directives

In my application core component is root component, In this page header , sidemenu designs are existed,

**SideMenu** is dynamic, so I write logic of the code in other sidemenu component,

Now I want to use the functionality of sidemenu in core component, I think it is 
done by using extends,

My componets are

core component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SidemenuComponent} from './sidemenu.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-admin',
  templateUrl: '../views/admin-header.html'
})

export class CoreComponent extends SidemenuComponent {

  constructor( private router: Router) {
    }

}
```

**sidemenucomponent**

```
import {OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {MenuService} from './core.service';

export class SidemenuComponent implements OnInit{
  userroleId : any;
  roleName: string;
  menuItems:any;
  constructor(private http: Http,private MenuService:MenuService) {
   this.userroleId =  localStorage.getItem("roleId")
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSideMenu();
  }

  getSideMenu () {
    if( this.userroleId == 1) {
      this.MenuService.getAdminMenu().subscribe(menuItems => this.menuItems= menuItems, error => console.log(error));
    }

    if(this.userroleId == 2){
      this.MenuService.getpractitionerMenu().subscribe(menuItems => this.menuItems= menuItems, error => console.log(error));
      console.log('ss')
    }
  }
}
```

**MenuService**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()

export class MenuService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public getAdminMenu(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./app/core/adminsidemenu.json")
      .map((res:any) => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  public getpractitionerMenu(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./app/core/practitioner.json")
      .map((res:any) => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

Here I am unable extends the sidemenu component in core component.
I am getting error in my console:

> Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.

Please help me

Comment: " I am unable extends the sidemenu component in core component" what do you men by "unable" ?

Comment: I am getting error in my console ** Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.**

Comment: I was unable to replicate this, do you have a plnkr? Purhaps try putting in `super(http, MenuService)` into CoreComponent's contructor, while CoreComponent contructor params contains those of SidemenuComponent.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be missing the `@Component` decorator on the SidemenuComponent.

Here's a Plunker with a [simple extended Component](http://plnkr.co/edit/76gWOLqGpgRhrF4Jn0c6?p=preview), and here's a good article on it: [Component Ineritance](https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2).

Comment: I don 't want to use @Component in my SidemenuComponent , for logic only I seperate componets, So that I can use it any other components

Comment: Well it is not a Component then is it? It is a Service! Why not just make it `@Injectable()` and inject it into the Core Component?

Comment: Can you Please tell how to make SidemenuComponent  as service,I am getting error ** @NgModule.entryComponents?**

Comment: Put `@Injectable()` above it and inject into CoreComponent's constructor as you have done with `MenuService`? And declare in providers in ngModule.

Comment: ya If I make sidemenu component as a service getting entrycomponents error

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the constructor of the parent class in your child-class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-admin',
  templateUrl: '../views/admin-header.html'
})

export class CoreComponent extends SidemenuComponent {

  constructor( private router: Router, http: Http, menuService:MenuService) {
     super(http,menuService);
  }

}
```

Comment: I am getting error like  ----Class 'CoreComponent' incorrectly extends base class 'SidemenuComponent'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'http'

Comment: you didn't provide enough informations, because there is no `http` declaration in the code you provided (for `CoreComponent`). I guess you don't understand what is private/protected/public modifiers, do you ? And I'm unsure you actualy want to extend `SideMenu`.

Comment: what exactly I want means, My corecomponet has so many lines of code, I  want to seperate some piece of code in other component, like that I can read my corecomponent code easily,

Comment: okay, I am new to angular2 , can you please tell me what to do

Comment: Do you have any Object-oriented programming background ? are you familiar with concepts such as inheritance, implementations (for interfaces), eventualy private/public/protected modifiers ?

Comment: Ok, so I won't bother you with the "should I extend ?" part, but the error `Types have separate declarations of a private property 'http"` means you have declared a private `http`property in `CoreComponent` **and** in `SideMenuComponent`, the property must be declared `protected` in the parent class (`SideMenuComponent`) and can be removed in the child-one (`CoreComponent`).